# Cannot create DB2 index, getting SQL30081N error

Tags: indexing, db2

Trying to create an index (and run some long queries) on DB2 v9.1 and failing with the following error message:

> SQL30081N (A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP". Communication API being used: "SOCKETS". Location where the error was detected: "". Communication function detecting the 
>   error...")

I have tried to follow advice given by IBM here regarding setting `QUERYTIMEOUTINTERVAL=0`- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg21164785 but it did not take.

any ideas? queries and commands seem to time out at about 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rule out any network interference by running the DDL and SQL locally on the server. By using nohup on UNIX or schtasks on Windows, you can start a DB2 job that will run to completion even if the database server loses all network connectivity.

Comment: Fred,

This is what we did as well after I posted the question. The indexing completed well. Thank you for your answer. I would upvote it, if I could, but I do not have the reputation points yet.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a network error, probably your client machine is losing the connection to the server. Are you over an unstable network connection, for example a VPN over the internet?